# Custom Dimension and Metrics in Google Analytics reports (Android SDK)

Tags: android, google-analytics

By using Google Analytics Android SDK 3, I can successfully can see my native Android application's statistics.

Regarding to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/customdimsmets#set-send) I created custom dimensions for my app. (It seems like no need to set dimensions from web interface. Coding is adequate)

```
// May return null if EasyTracker has not yet been initialized with a
// property ID.
EasyTracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance();

// Send the custom dimension value with a screen view.
// Note that the value only needs to be sent once, so it is set on the Map,
// not the tracker.
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder
    .createAppView("Home screen")
    .set(Fields.customDimension(1), "premiumUser");
    .build()
);
```

But when I check Google Analytics web interface I can't see my dimensions in any place. From "Screens" part of analytics there exists custom variables but there is no place for dimensions. How can I see the custom dimensions in analytics reports ?

Answer (score 3):

you have to create a custom report that includes you custom metrics, dimension ...,
from

> Customisation tab -> New custom report

Answer (score 0):

Besides the Custom Report method that Mouna mentioned, you can also see your custom data in the Reporting tab:

In the Reporting tab, click on the button called 'Secondary Dimension', and in the popup select the name of your custom dimension. This shows me a results page with a column for my custom dimension.

If you do not see any results, repeat the above after first trying different values for the Primary Dimension (ie, if you don't see any data when Primary Dimension is 'Event Label', then try again with Primary Dimension set to 'Event Category' or 'Event Action').